# Максимально возможное количество потоков в threading, для HTTP запросов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, какое максимальное количество потоков, можно создавать с помощью модуля threading, для HTTP запросов?

Comment: Это вы можете проверить самостоятельно для собственной ОС. Но если у вас возник этот вопрос, возможно, вы что-то делаете не так. Для одновременной работы с большим количеством сетевого ввода-вывода лучше использовать асинхронные инструменты.

Comment: Зависит от операционной системы и переменных окружения. Используйте multiprocessing чтобы не возникло таких ограничений.